# xamarin C# - httpwebrequest javascript enable

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin

Sorry about the repeated question.
So many questions about this, but I found no answer.
I had checked all google result as well but found nothing.
I just want a way to make httpwebrequest Enable javascript with it request.
Or any way to make web post request in xamarin android
C# to php page and get json response

My problem in httpwebrequest 
that the server respose always 
Return message ask to enable javascript

Q2 : Do we can to make webview to make this request
And save the webview response string 
In c# var ?

Comment: Your server is probably looking at the user-agent string to determine that JS is not enabled.  You could try masking this to trick the server; however, there is no way to "enable javascript" in a httpwebrequest.

Comment: In some free php hosting it work without any problem I don't understand way

Comment: Different hosts and servers and pages are setup differently.  There is no way to explain "why" a certain one is setup a certain way other than to ask the person who configured it.  In general, retrieving the source of a webpage via a http request in C# is simple to do and there are numerous samples available on SO and elsewhere.  It may be useful to use your browser's dev tools to examine the page load and see what is happening.

Comment: What question can i ask for this service ? In php webhost site